# how to remove black color from circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I make a high chart using highchart.js file .I need to remove blackhole or black dot which is display on centre .
http://jsfiddle.net/kbvC3/837/
here is my code

```
[![{

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'gauge',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBackgroundImage: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 0,
                    plotShadow: false,
                    height:240,
                    width:290
            },
          credits: {
              enabled: false
          },

            title: {
                text: ''
            },

            pane: {
                center: \['50%', '75%'\],
                    size: '100%',
                    startAngle: -120,
                    endAngle: 120,
                    background: \[{
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
                }\],
            },][1]][1]
```

[![enter code here][1]][1]`

could you please tell me how to remove this dot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That thing is called the pivot.

SO you can use something like this in the options:

```
pivot: {
   radius: 10,
   borderWidth: 1,
   borderColor: 'transparent',
   backgroundColor: 'transparent'
}
```

See this jsFiddle for a working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/kbvC3/838/

**edit** Just putting the `radius: 0` is actually enough to make it disappear.